# I want to remove underline from all links but this CSS from the twilight zone is terrorizing everywhere

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Check [this page](https://triplov.com/revistaTriplov/fragmentos-de-la-vida-y-obra-de-unica-zurn/).

At the end of this page you will find this phrase `21 MULHERES SURREALISTAS`. This is a link and is underlined.

Inspect this element. All `text-decoration` definitions on the CSS are `none` but this link still appears underlined.

How in the name of sanity I remove underline from all links on this site, including this?

I am searching for this for hours.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a box-shadow on the anchor tag. Specifically:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 hsl(250deg 50% 6%); 
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 hsl(250deg 50% 6%);
```

To remove it, just use:

```
.colors-custom .entry-content a, .colors-custom .entry-summary a, .colors-custom .widget a, .colors-custom .site-footer .widget-area a, .colors-custom .posts-navigation a, .colors-custom .widget_authors a strong {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: @Duck Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a selector set for a:hover as below, which sets a box-shadow, not a text decoration.

```
.colors-custom .entry-content a:hover, .colors-custom .entry-content a:focus, .colors-custom .entry-summary a:hover, .colors-custom .entry-summary a:focus, .colors-custom .widget a:hover, .colors-custom .widget a:focus, .colors-custom .site-footer .widget-area a:hover, .colors-custom .site-footer .widget-area a:focus, .colors-custom .posts-navigation a:hover, .colors-custom .posts-navigation a:focus, .colors-custom .widget_authors a:hover strong, .colors-custom .widget_authors a:focus strong {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%), 0 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%), 0 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0);
```

}